# Saving reference to a blob type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I want to save a reference to an image that will be stored in the database.
But I am not sure how to approach this in C# (Entityframework).

Using EF's code first approach.
In the Model class, must i do `String imageReference`, og must I use `byte`? Or is there another and better solution to this? What I want once the database is created, for that column, it should say Blob or what ever is used to hold large objects like images.

I am also thinking that only saving a reference in the database, instead of the image itself might be a solution. But I don't know which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create it as a byte, and your db should be blob

```
var image = new ImageEntity(){
   imageReference= convertImageToByteArray(image)
}
_Context.Images.Add(image);
_Context.SaveChanges();
```

Convert ur image to a byte array:

```
public byte[] convertImageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(memStream , ImageFormat.Gif); //u may choose other formats
    return memStream .ToArray();
}
```

I would recommend saving the file path as reference instead of storing it as a blob unless you have no choice. This is because a larger DB will degrade the performance, the hard disk would do a better job at handling files. If your image files are larger than 1MB, the file system has an advantage over a SQL Server. Also storing it in the file system has greater flexibility (i.e. you may migrate your files elsewhere next time, and change the link in the DB during migration, you can't do that on the DB)